# Solving linear modular equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

How does

$17r \equiv-2 \pmod {11} $

reduce to

$r\equiv-4 \pmod {11}$?

I know that $-2\equiv9 \pmod {11}$, but how do I simplify the $17$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's $6r$ cause $17r=11r+6r$
$$17r\equiv -2\pmod {11}\\6r\equiv-2\pmod{11}\\6r\equiv9\pmod{11}\\2r\equiv3\pmod{11}\\2r\equiv-8\pmod{11}\\r\equiv-4 \pmod{11}$$

Answer (score 4):

First, $17\equiv 6\pmod {11}$, and since we have $6r$ it would be helpful to find a number that is an inverse of $6$ modulo $11$.  A quick guess suggests that $6\cdot 2=12\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, and this means that $6^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod {11}$.

So we apply this as follows:

$$\begin{align}17r&\equiv -2\pmod{11}\\
\implies 6r&\equiv -2\\
\implies 6^{-1}\cdot 6r&\equiv 6^{-1}\cdot -2\\
\implies r\equiv 2\cdot -2&\equiv -4\pmod{11}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

${\rm mod}\ 11\!:\,\ \dfrac{-2}{17}\,\equiv\, \dfrac{20}{-5}\,\equiv\, -4$

Answer (score 1):

[For the following paragraphs, please refer to the figure at the end of the last paragraph ([the figure is also available in PDF](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/iLxxl1444461219.pdf)).]

The manipulations performed from steps (0) to (17) were designed to create the linear system of equations (2a), (7a), (12a) and (17a). The manipulations end when the absolute value of a coefficient of the latest equation added is 1 (see (17a)).

It is possible to infer equation (7a) from (2a) without performing manipulations (3) to (7) directly. It is also possible to infer equation (12a) from (7a), and equation (17a) from (12) without performing any of the manipulations. In every case, select the smallest absolute value coefficient, generate the next equation by replacing every coefficient with the remainder of the coefficient divided by the selected coefficient (smallest absolute value coefficient) – do the same with the right-hand constant – and add the new variable whose coefficient is the smallest absolute value coefficient. If the new equation has a greatest common divisor greater than one, divide the equation by the greatest common divisor. Stop when the absolute value of a coefficient of the latest equation added is 1.

To “simplify 17” is to perform substitution on or “solve” the linear system of equations: (2a), (7a), (12a) and (17a). When “solved”, the linear system has the following interesting property: every original variable (r, s) can be expressed in terms of parameter variables (t1, t2 and t3) where every coefficient in the parameter is integer.

[image]